# Django how to write PositiveDecimalField

Tags: django, django-models, django-validation

I'd like to write PositiveDecimalField.

Here is my code:

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _

from django.db.models import DecimalField
from decimal import *

def validate_positive_decimal(value):
    try:
        decimal_value = Decimal(value)

        if decimal_value < 0:
            raise ValidationError(_('{val} should be a positive decimal number'.format(val = decimal_value)), code='negative decimal')

    except (ValueError, TypeError):
        raise ValidationError(_('Enter a valid decimal or integer value'), code='invalid decimal')


class PositiveDecimalField(DecimalField):
    default_validators = [validate_positive_decimal]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        super(DecimalField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def validators(self):
        return super(PositiveDecimalField, self).validators + [validate_positive_decimal]
```

Then, in my models.py

```
class Service(models.Model):
    service_rate = PositiveDecimalField(max_digits = 6, decimal_places=2, blank=True) # e.g. 125.25 for water (demo phase), -125.25 should not be accepted
```

The error I get is this:

```
super(DecimalField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'max_digits'
```

I looked at the source code for Django's DecimalField in the docs.  I also tried to just pass the validator, validate_positive_decimal, to the DecimalField, but it does not validate against it.

What do I need to do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your call to `super()` in `__init__` should be

```
super(PositiveDecimalField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

instead of

```
super(DecimalField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 5):

I usually define such fields as:

```
from django.core.validators import MinValueValidator

pos_float_field = models.FloatField(validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0)])
```

It's cleaner this way.

Doc: [MinValueValidator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/validators/#minvaluevalidator)